# AWK / SED extract string between HUGE line

Tags: string, awk, sed, line, delimiter

I have a huge line that is a response from a ws, I need to get all the strings that are between `<asunto>` and `</asunto>`. The file is like this:

```
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Body><ns1:consultarComunicacionesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ve.tecno.afip.gov.ar/domain/service/ws"><ns2:RespuestaPaginada xmlns:ns2="http://ve.tecno.afip.gov.ar/domain/service/ws" xmlns:ns3="http://core.tecno.afip.gov.ar/model/ws/types" xmlns:ns4="http://ve.tecno.afip.gov.ar/domain/service/ws/types"><pagina>1</pagina><totalPaginas>1</totalPaginas><itemsPorPagina>100</itemsPorPagina><totalItems>2</totalItems><ns4:items><ns4:ComunicacionSimplificada><idComunicacion>sdfgsfdgsfdgsd</idComunicacion><cuitDestinatario>sdfgsdfgsdfgsfdg</cuitDestinatario><fechaPublicacion>sdfgsdfg</fechaPublicacion><fechaVencimiento>sdfgsdfgsdfg</fechaVencimiento><sistemaPublicador>sdfgsdfgsfg</sistemaPublicador><sistemaPublicadorDesc>sdfgsdfggf</sistemaPublicadorDesc><estado>2</estado><estadoDesc>sdfgsdfgsgf</estadoDesc><asunto>EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE1</asunto><prioridad>3</prioridad><tieneAdjunto>sdfgfdg</tieneAdjunto></ns4:ComunicacionSimplificada><ns4:ComunicacionSimplificada><idComunicacion>sdfgsdfgdfg</idComunicacion><cuitDestinatario>sdfgdfsg</cuitDestinatario><fechaPublicacion>sdfgsdfg</fechaPublicacion><fechaVencimiento>sdfgdsfg</fechaVencimiento><sistemaPublicador>sdfgsdfg</sistemaPublicador><sistemaPublicadorDesc>sdfgsdfgdsfggsdf</sistemaPublicadorDesc><estado>1</estado><estadoDesc>dsfgsdfgsgd</estadoDesc><asunto>EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE2</asunto><prioridad>asdfdsf</prioridad><tieneAdjunto>asdfasdf</tieneAdjunto></ns4:ComunicacionSimplificada></ns4:items></ns2:RespuestaPaginada></ns1:consultarComunicacionesResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I shuold get something like this:

```
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE1    
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE2
```

There may be a lot of repetition, between 0 and hundreds.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS='[<>]' '/\/asunto/{f=0;next} f; /asunto/{f=1}' file

EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE1
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE2
```

UPDATE: based on the comments if there is a chance that the tag exist in elsewhere you can anchor on the left and right of the open/close tags

```
$ awk -v RS='[<>]' '/^\/asunto$/{f=0;next} f; /^asunto$/{f=1}' file
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE1
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE2
```

or equivalently, check for an exact string match

```
$ awk -v RS='[<>]' '$0=="/asunto"{f=0;next} f; $0=="asunto"{f=1}' file
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE1
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE2
```

also note that not all `awk` variants support multi char RS.

Comment: You should mention it's gawk-specific due to the multi-char RS and it'll fail if `asunto` appears in other contexts than as a tag.

Comment: @karakfa - To address Ed's second point, could you change the one-liner slightly to: `awk -v RS='[<>]' '/\/asunto *$/{f=0;next} f; /^asunto/{f=1}' file` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **GNU** [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/).

```
grep -oP '(?<=<asunto>)((?!</asunto>).)+(?=</asunto>)' yourfile
```

This takes advantage of **Lookbehind** plus **Negative** and **Positive** **Lookahead**.

[Here's](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) a nice explanation of its internals.

**Performance**

```
$ wc -l bigfile 
100000 bigfile

$ time awk -v RS='</?asunto>' '!(NR%2)' bigfile >/dev/null

real  0m0.277s
user  0m0.254s
sys 0m0.022s


$ time grep -oP '(?<=<asunto>)((?!</asunto>).)+(?=</asunto>)' bigfile >/dev/null

real  0m4.318s
user  0m4.292s
sys 0m0.020s

$ time awk -v RS='[<>]' '/\/asunto/{f=0;next} f; /asunto/{f=1}' bigfile >/dev/null

real  0m7.088s
user  0m6.928s
sys 0m0.021s
```

**@Ed** code achieve the greatest performance by far.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='</?asunto>' '!(NR%2)' file
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE1
EXAMPLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an XML parser (and awk to remove the header)

```
awk -v RS= 'NR>1' ws.out | xmlstarlet sel  -t -v //asunto -n
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/<asunto>([^<]*)<\/asunto>/{s//\n\1\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;P;D}' file
```

This reduces the string to a prepended line and then prints, deletes this line and repeats. Lines not containing the required string are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out elsewhere, an XML-aware tool would in principle be safer, but the following GNU grep incantation may be useful if there is no nesting of the "asunto" tags, and will work even if the string between `<asunto>` and `</asunto>` is empty or contains other tags:

```
grep -oP '(?<=<asunto>).*?(?=</asunto>)'
```

The key here is the non-greedy subexpression: `.*?`